# Excel VBA でOutlookのメールを作成するのですが、実行後にメールの画面がアクティブにならないことがあるので、 アクティブ(最前面)にする方法を教えてください。

Tags: vba, excel, mail

Excel VBAでOutlookのメールを作成するのですが、実行後にメールの画面がアクティブにならないことがあります。 アクティブ(最前面)にする方法を教えてください。

コードは以下のような感じです。

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
 Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
 Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 With objMail
 .To = "xxxxxxx@xxxx.co.jp" 
 .Subject ="〇〇〇の件" 
 .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain 
 .Body = "メール本文" 
 .Display
 End With
```

Comment: この辺の組み合わせ等で考えられるかもしれません。[MailItem.GetInspector プロパティ (Outlook)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getinspector), [Inspector.Activate メソッド (Outlook)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(method))

Comment: ありがとうございます。
具体的なコードを教えていただけると大変助かります。

Comment: 私も検索して関連しそうだと想像しただけなので、詳細は使えるかどうかもわかりません。同様に連想して検索を続けるか、試すか等してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

私も同じことをやりたくてここにたどり着きました。

.Display
と
End With
の間に
.GetInspector.Activate
という1行を入れるとできました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
やってみましたが、まだうまく行かないようです。

Answer (score 1):

私も上記の修正では前面に来ないことが出てきました。

そこで、以下の通り書き換えて試しています。

**修正前:**

```
.GetInspector.Activate
```

**修正後:**

```
.GetInspector.Display (False)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。まだ様子見ですが、できたかもしれないです！